# Defining negative integers and rationals in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Given the structure $(\mathbb{R};+,\cdot)$ (the language is assumed to have equality and the parameters $\forall$, $+$, and $\cdot$), I want to define any natural, integer, and rational number. So far I have managed the following:

I have defined $0$ using the formula:
$$\exists v_2 \forall v_1 (v_2 + v_1 = v_1)$$

I have defined a given natural number $n$ using the formula:
$$\exists v_2 ((v_1=v_2 + \cdots + v_2) \wedge \forall v_3 (v_2 \cdot v_3 = v_3))$$
(where $v_2$ is added $n$ times).

I have defined a given rational number $\frac{m}{n}$ using the formula:
$$\exists v_2 ((v_1 + \cdots +v_1 = v_2+ \cdots + v_2) \wedge \forall v_3 (v_2 \cdot v_3 = v_3))$$
(where $v_1$ is added $n$ times and $v_2$ is added $m$ times).

I am stuck, however, in trying to define negative integers and negative rationals. 
Any help in solving that would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe, try to do it in a way like you defined the zero but with the condition that (v1+v2=0), where v2 is negative.

Comment: $\forall v_3(v_3+v_2\cdot v_3=0)$?